# Fastest cryptographically secure random number generator

Tags: c++, c, performance, random, cryptography

I am looking for a cryptographically secure random number generator in C/C++. The speed is very important because this will be used to generate terabytes of randomness in our application. I tried the one in libgcrypt but it is very slow. Any recommendations would be very helpful.

Comment: Sounds like you need more processing power.

Comment: And maybe a better source of entropy...you may want to look into an RNG card. Do you really need terabytes worth of cryptographically strong random bits? Would a PRNG work for most of that?

Comment: prng is okay.. but it has to cryptographically secure..

Answer (score 2):

Try ANSI X9.17 standard (Financial Institution Key Management (wholesale)).

The technique is described on this page:
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cryptographically_secure_pseudorandom_number_generator

You should be able to take any block cipher implementation, such as AES, and easily wrap it into fairly fast, reasonably secure random number generator with just a few lines using this technique.

Answer (score -2):

Do you really need cryptographically secure, or do you just need really good random numbers with long cycle?

Mersenne Twister using SIMD - SFMT - is fast and good.

/dev/random on BSDs is typically Yarrow, which is cryptographically secure.

Fortuna is the followup to Yarrow.

If you want CSPRNG that trumps speed surely?

Comment: it's a cryptographic protocol.. so it has to be CSPRNG.. was just looking for the fastest csprng i.e., the fastest of the csprings out there..